# What's a professional way of saying "I'll keep this time frame available"?

Tags: phrase-request

In job hunting, when scheduling for phone interviews, I usually give them the times that I'm available. Then I'd follow with a sentence: "Please let me know if you plan to call at a certain time frame so I can keep it available."

What I mean is that I'll make sure I don't add other appointments on that time frame. Am I saying it correctly or are there better/more concise way of saying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence choice is fine and will be clear. However, it is a bit wordy. If you give them your available times, you don't have to re-say available.

> Here are my available times. Please schedule the time so I may keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

I've often heard this as "pencil it in" as in reserving time for something which may or may not happen.

This references the fact that on a paper calendar, pencil marks can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is a bit informal since the interviewer would want me to take it seriously. Therefore it's not the best answer for this question. However, I've learned something new and it'll be useful in other scenarios. I will give you an vote up once I have the privilege to do so.